# Remove module folder when uninstalling

Tags: 7, installation

is there any method/module that allow removing module folder when uninstalling the module
or delete the files via dashboard

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use case for this?

Comment: Automatically replace files when new version is released.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. You don't want to un-install a module to perform an upgrade.

Comment: If you want to "automatically replace files when a new version is released", you can use Drush.  Drush allows you to enter a command like "drush up views" to automatically update Views to the latest version.

Answer (score 10):

To take a different angle:

It's very possible to do this, **but you shouldn't**. Your web server user should not have the capacity to write to the web root (except for designated folders like the public files folder). You should therefore not be able to delete module folders from code. Doing so presents a security risk to your server.

This is one of the checks the [Security Review](http://drupal.org/project/security_review/) module performs, and throws up a nice big red error if it find the web server *can* write to such files:

[image]

I understand this might be unavoidable if you're on shared hosting, but I think it's a good piece of information to have either way.

Comment: If I could edit this to make all of the text bold, red, and blinking, I would.

Comment: @MPD Shame the `<marquee>` and `<blink>` tags aren't available in Markdown eh? ;) I've tried to make it a bit more shouty, hopefully the point will get across

Answer (score 2):

A module *could* implement [hook_modules_uninstalled](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_uninstalled/7) to do this for other modules, but I'm not aware of such a module, no.

Comment: `hook_uninstall` only "Remove any information that the module sets."

Comment: I agree to @NikhilM ; OP is asking for a method to remove the module folder on uninstalling it..

Comment: @NikhilM I was a bit to quick to write there >_< I didn't mean a module could do it for _itself_, but for others, though I refered to a hook that isn't invoked for other modules. Fixed that now.

Comment: @Letharion, Saw the edit, Seems helpful for the OP now.

Comment: I think we need a cpanel module to browse the _sites_ directory